# S3 Boto3 python - change all files acl to public read

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to change ACL of 500k files within a S3 bucket folder from 'private' to 'public-read'

**Is there any way to speed this up?**

I am using the below snippet.

```
from boto3.session import Session
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(processes=100)

BUCKET_NAME = ""
aws_access_key_id = ""
aws_secret_access_key = ""
Prefix='pics/'

session = Session(aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
_s3 = session.resource("s3")
_bucket = _s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

def upload(eachObject):
    eachObject.Acl().put(ACL='public-read')

counter = 0
filenames = []
for eachObject in _bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=Prefix):
    counter += 1
    filenames.append(eachObject)
    if counter % 100 == 0:
        pool.map(upload, filenames)
        print(counter)
if filenames:
    pool.map(upload, filenames)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can tell, without applying the ACL to the entire bucket, there is no way to simply apply the ACL to all items containing the same prefix without iterating through each item like below:

```
bucketName='YOUR_BUCKET_NAME'
prefix="YOUR_FOLDER_PREFIX"

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucketName)

[obj.Acl().put(ACL='public-read') for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix).all()]
```